# Ubuntu-touch ruby / rails development: installing with rvm

Tags: ubuntu-touch, git, ruby, ruby-on-rails, libertine

I have a Bq10 tablet running Ubuntu-touch OTA-11. I want to be able to work with Ruby and rails apps.

Usually I use [rvm](https://rvm.io)  for this.

Is it possible to install rvm [or something similiar] using ubuntu-touch and the libertine containers?

So far I have had lots of trouble installing rails via rvm. The typical command is 
`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`

I have tried lots of variations of installing it with libertine-container-manager but none have been successful.

If I enter the container I get the following error:

`root@ubuntu-phablet:/# \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.27.0.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.27.0/1.27.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: fatal: can't create directory`/home/phablet/.gnupg': No such file or directory`

What does work is to add a new user within the container and then issue the normal commands. Within the container this will allow me to install ruby and rails with rvm but I can't access any rvm commands from outside the container.

Is there a possible solution to this?

**Note** I guess this question might be generalised to more than just rvm, it could be about installing software with git, or issuing commands which pipe text into bash ...

Comment: Where are you running those commands? Your best bet is to install a terminal emulator (such as Terminator) in the container and then run the required commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the error you're getting.  I see rvm download a slew of arbitrary shell script commands from site on the internet which it then tries to run as the superuser using sudo.  My imagination is sparkled by so many possible ways to own someone's system right now.

Anyway, to test this is had a container with a terminal installed (in my case, I used sakura).  Using a terminal app lets you run as the phablet user, no need to add another user.  I used the libertine-container-manager CLI tools to install the curl command but the sudo command isn't available, because that would let you break containment, so the installation failed.

You're not going to be able to run contained applications from outside the container because that would break confinement.

Comment: I didn't post all the steps, though perhaps I should have. The first command is to verify the gpg identity of rvm.

I got the error you did about sudo and this is why I created a new user (and then installed sudo).

You're right about the container and confinement - though you can run commands with " libertine-container-manager exec -c "COMMAND' -i container-name"

Comment: 'The first command is to verify the gpg identity of rvm.' --  sure, it told me how to do that and gave me the URL to type to download the keys used to verify, which is wonderful if you're the man in the middle, you can prove you're the legitimate source.

Comment: You're right - there are issues to the way rvm is installed. 

It is a standard way to install ruby for rails development however. I would like to use it, or an alternative method to hack on rails apps.

Comment: Despite all the errors I got about sudo, it appears rvm is installed and runs OK from my terminal.